# Check if optional chaining is supported

Tags: javascript

I want to use a polyfill for optional chaining but I do not want to provide a polyfill for browsers which already support this feature.

Is there a way to determine whether a browser supports optional chaining ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```js
const isOptionalChainingSupported = () => {
  try {
    eval('const foo = {}; foo?.bar');
  } catch {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: This should be `} catch (e) {` as the whole function will error out on internet exploder without it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solutions online. I managed to come up with this:

```
const getIsOptionalChainingSupported = () => {
  try {
    const test = {};
    const isUndefined = test?.foo?.bar
    if (isUndefined === undefined) {
      return true
    }
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: You can drop the `if` statement. The condition always evaluates to `true`.

Comment: To be more precise: It would always fall in the catch if it throws, rather than always evaluates to `true`. Removed the condition :)

Comment: I've tried this approach, but it didn't work. It throws an Uncaught SyntaxError when there's no support, which doesn't work with try/catch. Is there something else I must do to make it work?

Comment: @LincolnAlves I had the same problem. My open source contributor solved it by putting the detection algorithm in a file that's dynamically loaded. Look here: https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/blob/main/projects/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/src/lib/options/pdf-viewer-application-options.ts and https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/blob/b03b866a2c50bf50263eecfa65770c3c8f5b21f4/projects/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/src/lib/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer.component.ts#L722.

Comment: Hey @StephanRauh !
Actually I'm the one who mad that contribution hahah! I was still searching for the best approach when I asked here!

Comment: Oops - I knew your name sounds familiar :)

Comment: This results in a syntax error when optional chaining is not supported